# GoogleIdToken-Sub and OpenID values are the same

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-authentication

I'm using google-oauth2 authentication workflow in my app which supports login with google accounts.

My question is when I get the ID-Token from google it returns the same OpenID(2.0) value as the Sub.

Is that the expected behaviour or is it due to some issue with the authentication-request/workflow (shown below) ?

Authentication Request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&
response_type=code&
scope=email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.
email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar+https%3A%2F
%2Fdocs.
google.com%2Ffeeds+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.
com%2Fauth%2Fdocs+https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Ffeed%2Fatom&
redirect_uri=http://example.com/oauth2/callback/google.json&
state=e410b0ae-696a-4b7d-9f3e-aec14c1acdd1&
access_type=offline&
openid.realm=http://example.com&
login_hint=fake_user@testedu.info&
hd=testedu.info
```

In the callback, the following code snippet is used to get Token from Google for the "code" value returned to the callback.

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenResponse = new 
GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, 
googleAppClientId,googleAppClientSecret, code, callbackurl).execute();
```

Following are the existing OpenID2.0 value in DB and the new Sub value returned in GoogleIdToken. 
sub is extacted as : "idToken.getPayload().getSubject()"

Existing OpenID : 107287433969474xxxxxx

Sub         : 107287433969474xxxxxx